# PHP search directory load <p> tag from files

Tags: php, fopen, strip-tags

So I need to have a search query done and load any `<p>` tags in any of the HTML pages and load them under the link to give a short description.  so far I got most of the search done but I am having issues with `<p>` tags loading.  my idea was to use "fopen" and then "strip_tags" to pull the `<p>` tags and then echo them under the link to the HTML document.

so far i have this

```
$directory = "test/";


if ($submitbutton){
if (!empty($searchoriginal))
{
if (is_dir($directory)){

  if ($open = opendir($directory)){
if ($countsearchterms == 1)
{
    while (($file = readdir($open)) !== false){
    $filecom= $file;
    $file= strtolower($file);
    $file= str_replace("-", " ", $file);
    $file= str_replace("_", " ", $file);
    

 $text = fopen("$file" , "r");

    $position= strpos("$file", ".");
    $file= substr($file, 0, $position);

      if (strpos("$file",  "$search[0]") !== false)
    {        
    $file= ucwords($file);
    $array[] += "$file";
     echo "<a href='http://website here/$directory" . "$filecom'>$file</a>"."<br>";
      echo strip_tags($text, '<p>');
      echo "\n";
}
```

but after I add "fopen" and echo from "$file" the website will freeze and then crash.

Comment: An HTML-aware parser like DOMDocument and [`getElementsByTagName`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) would be my suggestion

Comment: Why are you applying strtolower, and replacing characters in the filenames you just read from the directory? How do you expect `fopen` to be able to open the file then - if you _mess up_ its name?

Comment: And if you are reading your file names from a different directory than the current one - then you need to include that directory name in what you are passing to `fopen` as well.

Answer (score 0):

ok so I was able to figure out.

```
$St1 = file_get_contents("http://website here/$directory" . "$filecom");
 echo strip_tags($St1, '<p>');
```

basically it would use the full filename and them get the contents   afterwards I would just get the tags from it and then echo on the page.

idk why I did not think of this before but it works.